# Will resercher lose funding for taking maternity leave?

Tags: legal-issues

According to Rhiannon Pugh [tweet](https://twitter.com/PughRhiannon/status/1199730133378183169).

> I'm sad that the funding we were successfully granted has been revoked because I am going on maternity leave and apparently an extension to account for this is beyond the remit of the funders. It's hard to win funding, to have it taken away again after so much work is gutting

I haven't lived in Sweden for more than 10 years, but are these kind of things legal?

Especially in Europe/EU.

My friend is an assist. prof in Czech Republic and the only thing that was different during her maternity leave is that she received 80% salary.

Comment: This will be down to the conditions stipulated by the controllers of the funding, ask them.

Comment: @SolarMike but isnt usually there PI and coPI? she claims PhD students will lose funding as if she is only  advisor. Sound strange. is it possible?

Comment: Are twitter posts a contract or more of a rant? much may be strange but the funders have policies which they abide by, until you know what those policies are what can you say?

Comment: @SolarMike do you have any evidence that in Sweden is ok to discriminate base on maternity?

Comment: I am not saying anything is ok.... But until **you** read the policies you know nothing.

Comment: The question and the body text don't seem to agree what the question is.

Comment: I think it is discrimination against someone who cannot perform a study which was funded. Which would be most likely legal.